# Getting column value in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a table named students.
I need to get email field from specific students
for example, I get the following output in IRB

```
    Student.all

    Student Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "students".* FROM "students" 
    => [#<Student id: 1, name: "Bob", grade: 1, email_address: "bob@school.com", created_at:           "2014-03-27 08:55:51", updated_at: "2014-03-27 08:55:51">, #<Student id: 2, name: "Neo", grade: 1,       email_address: "robert@neo.com", created_at: "2014-03-27 08:56:05", updated_at: "2014-03-27 08:56:05">, #<Student id: 3, name: "Phil", grade: 3, email_address: "phil@school.com", created_at: "2014-03-27 08:56:21", updated_at: "2014-03-27 08:56:21">]
```

now I need to get email addresses of grade 1 students.
How could I get it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved it,
it can be done by using [pluck](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck) function:

```
    mail_addresses = Student.where(grade: 1).pluck(:email_address) 

    mail_addresses.each do|a|
      puts a
    end
```

Output :

```
    bob@school.com
    robert@neo.com
    => ["bob@school.com", "robert@neo.com"]
```

Voila!

Answer (score 2):

I think that it will help you.

There are many way to write queries to get email addresses of student with grade 1.

```
Student.where(:grade => 1).map(&:email)
```

or

```
 Student.where(:grade => 1).collect(&:email)
```

or

```
 Student.where("grade = ?", 1).map(&:email)
```

or

```
Student.find(:all, :conditions => ["grade = ?", 1]).map(&:email)
```

you can use select also.

```
 Student.where("grade = ?", 1).select("email").map(&:email)
```

always use rails query with `where` instead of `find`. rails query with `where' is working  fast instead of find.